# Mail Chimp subscriber string

Tags: email, mailchimp

Does anyone know how to get the relevant u code in this strng from mail chimp? they used to have chiclets that included this string but not anymore.

Here is an example of one that works and outputs that number:

http://themebeans.us6.list-manage2.com/subscriber-count?b=00&u=57e41705-395c-4dc2-a09b-78cff10f08f6&id=739445b065

I have tried to follow this method with mine e.g.:

http://richpearsondesigner.us7.list-manage.com/subscriber-count?b=1&u=5b14adb7f3334132a65f527cb&id=e98cecd630

However as you can see when you add both URL's to the browser themebeans works and mine errors, I'm assuming it's the 5b14adb7f3334132a65f527cb part that is wrong (no - in the string)

Any help from anyone pleaseeeee.

Answer (score 0):

So, a quick look through the coding on this Smashing Magazine page revealed the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript" src="http://smashingmagazine.us1.list-manage1.com/subscriber-count?b=34&amp;u=e768e688-36c3-4c2d-88fa-982d9d3f254b&amp;id=a1666656e0"></script>
```

Note how this script simply relies on the user knowing the correct information for the various parameters. This means we can go and find out what our ‘list-manage.com’ datacenter is, our ‘u’ ID number is, and finally our ‘ID’ number.

**How to**

Log into your MailChimp account and select the list you wish to use for your subscriber count button. Select Signup Forms then Embedded, so that we can reveal the code used to make a signup form specifically for the selected list.

Select the Naked option, and you should see code similar to the following:

```
<!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
<div id="mc_embed_signup">
<form action="http://YOUR-USERNAME-HERE.YOUR-DC.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=YOUR-U-NUMBER&amp;id=YOUR-ID-NUMBER" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
```

So we simply replace these details with those in the code above, and we get your very own Subscriber Count Button!

*Originally posted [here](http://grh.am/mailchimp-subscriber-buttons.html)*

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: Link is now broken (which is why link-only answers are discouraged)

Comment: Fixed to include everything here, and fix the link.